# My Android Game keeps Stopping after published on Play store! Works fine with apk

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, google-play, apk

I made my android game in buildbox 2 and converted, made it publishing ready through android studio(Apk signing, sdk version update,etc.)
I then converted it into a debugged apk and tried to test it on my phone, and it was working fine.
I was successfully able to publish app on google play without any errors (except of the alert - "Your game has incorrectly implemented the following Play Games services: Achievements. Affects APK version 5.)

days after my app was live on play store. But when I download it from there and try to open it, it keeps stopping. "myapp keeps stopping" message comes every time I try to open it. I have tried the usual techniques like clearing up cache and allowing permissions, but it isn't working.
I can't understand, my app was working fine as an apk but crashes when downloaded through play store.

what should I do? what should I modify?

Comment: implement a crash reporting service to find logs of what's wrong, then debug it, further than that we can't really help here

Comment: The google play console provides Crash Reports for you. Select you app > Android Vitals > ANRs and Crashes. You should be able to find the crash report here as a good starting point. I have had a similar issue as you have when I implemented a foreground service without adding the FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission to the manifest file.